# Access > Case for multiple fields

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, case

I have an Access database with some products. They were grouped by product reference. Additional there ate two columns that count the number of color-variations and sizes for each reference.

So I've got the fields [refID], [colors] and [sizes]

Now I want to use this information to calculate some cases that will become handy later. And that's where I need help.
I'm still a beginner but I thought about something like this:

```
Public Function variantCase() As Integer

[sizes] = sizes
[colors] = colors

    Select Case Variante
       Case sizes > 0 And colors < 1
          variant = 1
       Case sizes > 0 And colors > 1
          variant = 2
    End Select
End Function
```

Please note that those two cases are only examples. There will be min. 7 more.

But this doesn't seem to work yet.

---

UPDATE:

It's been a while, but I still need some help.
What I got so far is:

```
Public Function containerVariant()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = Application.CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("MyTable")

    Dim NumberOfSizes As String
    Dim NumberOfColors As String
    Dim Variant As String

Select Case NumberOfSizes
       Case Is > 0
           Select Case NumberOfColors
               Case Is < 0
                    Variant = 1
               Case Is > 0
                    Variant = 2
           End Select

       Case Else
           Variant = 9
End Select

End Function
```

At least I don't get any error-message, but this doesn't seem to do anything. I embedded the function to the Access SQL, but all fields of my new Variant-Column are still empty.
So, what Do I need to add/change to see the result in my Access Table?

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a view?

```
create view v_products as
    select p.*,
           iif(sizes > 0 And colors < 1, 1,
               iif(sizes > 0 And colors > 1, 2, NULL)) as variant
    from products as p;
```

Then just access the view to get the pseudo-column `variant`.

Comment: Hmmm, I should say, those two cases are just examples. There will be at least 7 more. And I thought it might be easier to handle by using cases.

Comment: @Manisch . . . One option is to nest the `iif()` expressions.  An alternative is to use the `switch` function (https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try nested CASE statements?  The way you've shown is NOT checking for one single variable, which I believe is how CASE works.

```
Select Case Sizes
       Case > 0
           Select case colors
               Case is < 0
                    variant = 1
               Case is > 0
                    variant = 2
           End Select

       Case ELSE
           ' etc, etc, etc
End Select
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution. Where are the number of "sizes" mentioned?

Comment: I guess I have to ask one more simple thing: How do I actually call the Access columns in vba? Seems like I'm still doing something wrong there. The columns are named "NumberofSIZE" and "NumberofCOLOR". Or in other words: what should the complete setup look like?

Comment: You need to open the table's RECORDSET and loop through the records to test for each case.  Research recordsets - there should be plenty of info here.

Comment: Thanks, I looked it up, but I'm not sure I did it right. I updated the OP. Could you please have another look at it?

Comment: Instead of variables, use the values in your recordset.   Eg.  'rs.variant = 2' and similar.   Remeber that you need to declare the rs.edit before assigning the value, and rs.update after.   Look those properties up.